# Interactive sub-heatmap (complexheatmap) doesn't load and gets stuck on the loading screen (attached screenshot). Any idea how to resolve this?

Tags: r, heatmap, complexheatmap

I'm using ComplexHeatmap and InteractiveComplexHeatmap packages in R by Zuguang Gu.
I'm using R Studio. When I plot interactive heatmap using

```
htShiny(cormap)
```

, I get the interactive heatmap, but when click on interactive sub-heatmap, it just open up the widget and shows loading screen Recursive sub-heatmap stuck. Any idea how to resolve this?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

```
sessionInfo()

R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.utf8    

time zone: Asia/Calcutta
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.8.0                     InteractiveComplexHeatmap_1.9.2 dendextend_1.17.1              
[4] circlize_0.4.15                 randomcoloR_1.1.0.1             ComplexHeatmap_2.15.4          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] gtable_0.3.4        shape_1.4.6         rjson_0.2.21        xfun_0.42           bslib_0.6.1        
 [6] ggplot2_3.4.4       GlobalOptions_0.1.2 vctrs_0.6.5         tools_4.3.2         stats4_4.3.2       
[11] curl_5.2.0          parallel_4.3.2      tibble_3.2.1        fansi_1.0.6         cluster_2.1.4      
[16] pkgconfig_2.0.3     RColorBrewer_1.1-3  S4Vectors_0.40.2    lifecycle_1.0.4     compiler_4.3.2     
[21] stringr_1.5.1       textshaping_0.3.7   munsell_0.5.0       fontawesome_0.5.2   codetools_0.2-19   
[26] clue_0.3-65         httpuv_1.6.14       htmltools_0.5.7     sass_0.4.8          yaml_2.3.8         
[31] pillar_1.9.0        later_1.3.2         crayon_1.5.2        jquerylib_0.1.4     ellipsis_0.3.2     
[36] rsconnect_1.2.1     cachem_1.0.8        iterators_1.0.14    viridis_0.6.5       foreach_1.5.2      
[41] mime_0.12           digest_0.6.34       Rtsne_0.17          stringi_1.8.3       fastmap_1.1.1      
[46] colorspace_2.1-0    cli_3.6.2           magrittr_2.0.3      utf8_1.2.4          scales_1.3.0       
[51] promises_1.2.1      rmarkdown_2.25      matrixStats_1.2.0   gridExtra_2.3       ragg_1.2.7         
[56] clisymbols_1.2.0    png_0.1-8           GetoptLong_1.0.5    memoise_2.0.1       kableExtra_1.4.0   
[61] evaluate_0.23       knitr_1.45          IRanges_2.36.0      V8_4.4.1            doParallel_1.0.17  
[66] viridisLite_0.4.2   rlang_1.1.3         Rcpp_1.0.12         xtable_1.8-4        glue_1.7.0         
[71] xml2_1.3.6          BiocGenerics_0.48.1 svglite_2.1.3       rstudioapi_0.15.0   jsonlite_1.8.8     
[76] R6_2.5.1            systemfonts_1.0.5
```

I tried installing both the ComplexHeatmap and InteractiveComplexHeatmap from github rather than bioconductor. But that doesn't seem to work. I don't know what's causing this issue.